# Load CSV memory pool error: "The memory pool limit was exceeded"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to load a large CSV to Neo4j 5.2 with `cypher-shell` and run into an error I have not seen before. Neo4j runs in Docker, I use  `cypher-shell` in the Docker container with `docker exec ... cypher-shell`:

```
Unable to complete transaction.: The memory pool limit was exceeded. The corresponding setting can be found in the error message
```

The Neo4j logs are empty, the heap size is 5 times larger than the total file size. The transaction should even fit into memory but I use `CALL ... IN TRANSACTIONS`.

The query should not run into an Eager operator:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///omop/CONCEPT_RELATIONSHIP_clean.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ','

CALL {
  WITH line
  MATCH (source:Concept { concept_id: line.concept_id_1 })
  MATCH (target:Concept { concept_id: line.concept_id_2 })
  CREATE (source)-[r:VOCAB_REL]->(target)
  SET r.type = line.relationship_id, r.valid_start_date = line.valid_start_date, r.valid_end_date = line.valid_end_date, r.invalid_reason = line.invalid_reason

} IN TRANSACTIONS;
```

Any ideas what could cause the error?

Answer (score 0):

The default batch size for CALL {} in transactions is 1k rows. Thus this may not be enough for a large transactional calls. You can adjust it probably from 5k to 10k of rows.

For example:

```
LOAD CSV FROM <csvfile> AS line
CALL {  ...
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 10000 ROWS
```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/#_batching

However, I would propose an alternative solution which uses apoc iterate function.  Please ensure that your csv file has no duplicate rows. Thanks.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
'
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///omop/CONCEPT_RELATIONSHIP_clean.csv' AS line RETURN line
','
  MATCH (source:Concept { concept_id: line.concept_id_1 })
  MATCH (target:Concept { concept_id: line.concept_id_2 })
  CREATE (source)-[r:VOCAB_REL]->(target)
  SET r.type = line.relationship_id, r.valid_start_date = line.valid_start_date, r.valid_end_date = line.valid_end_date, r.invalid_reason = line.invalid_reason
',
{batchSize:10000, parallel:True}) YIELD batches, total
RETURN batches, total
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an idea why the query throws a memory error? I would not expect an Eager operator.

Comment: You need to fine tune the call transaction settings. Use 5k or 10k and test it out. Other than that, you can use APOC or other methods of loading csv files like using neo4j-admin.

Comment: But why should a larger transaction help with the memory error?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///omop/CONCEPT_RELATIONSHIP_clean.csv" AS 
line FIELDTERMINATOR ','
WITH line
MATCH (source:Concept { concept_id: line.concept_id_1 })
MATCH (target:Concept { concept_id: line.concept_id_2 })
CALL {
  WITH line,source,target
  CREATE (source)-[r:VOCAB_REL]->(target)
  SET r.type = line.relationship_id, r.valid_start_date = 
  line.valid_start_date, r.valid_end_date = line.valid_end_date, 
  r.invalid_reason = line.invalid_reason
}
IN TRANSACTIONS OF 1000 ROWS;
```

And check whether you have index for concept_id on Concept Node.

Hope this helps!